# How to select elements with spacing inbetween

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, canvas, graph

Using JavaScript I created a graph consisting of a bunch of little squares. Between those squares is always some spacing.

Now I want to apply an effect on the graph when the mouse cursor **hovers over a graph**.

**Each square represents an element in an array and is positioned using modulo.**

```
rects = s.rect(positionX, positionY, 2, 2);

function drawEle1(index, element) {
   var x = (index % 4)*4;
   var y = 1080 - Math.floor(index/4)*4;
   TweenMax.to($(element), 1, {attr: {x: x, y: y, width: 2, height: 2, fill: "red"}});
}

$(".Ele1").each(drawEle1);
```

The squares all have the same class so I tried with `hover()` but because they are very small (2px) it doesn't work the way it should.

```
function lowOpacity(index, element) {
    TweenMax.to($(element), 0.5, {opacity: 0.5});
}

function highOpacity(index, element) {
    TweenMax.to($(element), 1, {opacity: 0.5});
}

//Functions for hover()
function opacityDown () {
    $(".Ele1").each(lowerOpacity)
}

function opacityUp () {
    $(".Ele1").each(raiseOpacity)
}

$(".Ele1").hover(opacityDown, opacityUp);
```

When the mouse cursor enters the graph or the blue boundaries all squares inside that graph should change opacity.

[image]

So basically I think I need a bounding box around the graph and check if the cursor is over the boundaries or not. To retrieve the position of the graph I could maybe use position().

Are my thoughts correct or is there a quicker and simpler way of doing this? How do I do this using position?

Comment: do you want to change opacity when it comes over a square or your whole object, by this I mean should you object change opacity even if your mouse is over spaces?

Comment: You can use CSS like `.graph:hover .square { opacity: 1 }`.

Comment: can you post you code?

Comment: @JSmith Yes ofc.